# How to pixelate Unicode characters in CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, pixelate

How would I pixelate a font in CSS or JavaScript? I don’t know how to do this and Google didn’t help.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by pixelate? Is your objective to obscure the text so it isn't readable?

Comment: No, just pixelate enough so that you can still read it, but it looks like an 80s video game thing. Or better.

Comment: You're going to need a font for that.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is a 16 bit font not need for Javascript, you can search it online as there are tons of free 16 bit fonts, example [from google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Press+Start+2P?selection.family=Press%20Start%202P) is something like this :

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<p>
This is a 16 bit web font!
</p>
```